# Does iCloud Keychain require 2fa in macOS 10.15 Catalina?

Tags: icloud, keychain, catalina

I've installed Catalina on a partition on my 2012 MacBook Air. However, when I go to set up iCloud Keychain, it asks me to set up 2FA, and then when I decline, it just says "Setting Up" and eventually goes to sleep. Is this a bug or a security feature?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.